# is 'data' wrapper for graphql obsolete for responses

Tags: graphql

why does grapql use 'data' wrapper in responses?
[here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fields)

For request:

```
{
  hero {
    name
  }
}
```

we got response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "hero": {
      "name": "R2-D2"
    }
  }
}
```

But why not just:

```
{
    "hero": {
      "name": "R2-D2"
    }
}
```

Is thad data-wrapper is obsolete already (jut the doc is not up-to-date)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `data` field because in addition there can be an `errors` field, too. In fact, if the query errored, there may only be an `errors` field and no data. In addition to those two, it's also possible to have a third key called `extensions` for - you guessed it - custom extensions.

For more information, read section 7.2  of the [GraphQL Draft Specification](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Response-Format).

Comment: Also you can get a response with `data` and `error` fields altogether. Thats why you need to have wrapped the result.

Answer (score 0):

The result is divided into 3 objects: loading, errors and data.

If there was no error, its placeholder will be empty.

You can find a more detailed explanation about the error logic in the following link: http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Errors